# Resetting Constraints to Screen Location Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, constraints

Currently, I have a Pan Gesture that moves an UIImageView by continuously changing the center of an image using something like this:

```
if let view = recognizer.view {
    view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                          y:view.center.y + translation.y)
}
```

I also want to alter text labels every second (timer) and this resets the moved UIImageView to default constraints because of auto layout format. I've seen that the proper way to move UIImageViews is to change the constraints of the UIImageView and not the center. Is there any way to change the constraints of an UIImageView to fit the current position of the image? I tried using

```
view.updateConstraints()
```

but that did not fix it. Ideally, it would behave like the "reset to suggested constraints" option when setting up constraints manually on storyboard, but used in the ViewController Class instead. I'm trying to avoid setting up all the constraints as IBOutlets and editing them like that as I have a lot of images with multiple constraints and multiple Pan Gestures that would need modifying.

Comment: did you try view.setNeedsLayout() and view.layoutIfNeeded() ?

Comment: @Stefan I tried just adding those two methods into the Pan Gesture selector, but it didn't have a noticeable effect. I tried looking into what those methods do, but I'm very new to Swift so it's possible that there is more to using those commands than just adding them into the Pan Gesture selector.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to reset to suggested constraints automatically. You can do it manually by updating the constants in the constraints.

You can't set position constraints equal to a constant, so you'll need to start with constraints relative to another object and modify them. For example, set the center to match the center of the superview, then change the constant to shift it to match the current state.

To do that, you'll need references to the constraints. You can either make your `NSLayoutConstraints` in Interface Builder and link to them with `IBOutlets`, or just create them programmatically. For the latter, declare them as instance properties of your view controller and then create them in its `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: x.view, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: x.view.superview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: x.view, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: x.view.superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
x.view.superview.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
```

When you want to update them, just change the constant:

```
let superview = x.view.superview
let currentOffsetX = x.view.center.x - superview.center.x
let currentOffsetY = x.view.center.y - superview.center.y

horizontalConstraint.constant = currentOffsetX
verticalConstraint.constant = currentOffsetY
```

Comment: I tried adding these constraints, but I'm getting an error as it interferes with other constraints already set on the UIImageView. I was avoiding this as there's a lot of constraints set on the UIImageViews already as the suggested constraints set to their neighbors. Would it be wiser to just remove autolayout and just do all my constraints programmatically even though its a pain for a lot of images?

Comment: @esimran Just figure out which constraints are causing conflicts, then set IBOutlets so you can access them, and change those constraints instead. If they're not `.centerX` and `.centerY` constraints then you might have to do some calculations to set them.

Comment: As a test, I've removed all constraints on any of the UIImageViews. I declared var verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(), added the constraints verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondCard, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: secondCard.center.y).  secondCard is the UIImageView. I updated constraints using verticalConstraint.constant = view.center.y, but error of  "multiplier of 0/nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant"

Comment: @esimran My mistake, I forgot that only `.width` and `.height` can be equal to a constant. You'll have to use constraints that place your view relative to something else, then add a constant to modify them. How you set that up will depend on your layout. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Now I'm getting a view hierarchy problem. "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint. When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself)." Is the problem that we are referencing the superview when we need to access the view or the descendants?

Comment: @esimran Oops yeah, the constraints need to be added to the superview (so that both views involved are contained within it) not x.view as I had it. Fixed now.